# Select an element that doesn't have a background set

Tags: jquery, css, select, styles, element

Using jQuery, I need to select all elements that do not have a background color or image defined, and apply at least a white background to it.

Comment: @tscully, why do you need to use jQuery to do this?

Comment: I'm creating a content slider using jQuery and I would like to make it as user-friendly as possible. e.g. if a designer doesn't set a background color/image, it will set one for them so the slider still looks right.

Comment: Yes, why not define a css rule like *{background-color:#FFF;}

Comment: because if the designer does set a background color/image, that would overwrite their style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which specific elements you're looking for you could do something like this:

```
var els = $('div');

els.each(function(idx, el){
    if ($(el).css('background-color') == '' || $(el).css('background-image') == '')
    {
        $(el).addClass('white-background');
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, so this worked great! The only thing now, is that it doesn't detect styles applied via a css file...only inline styles. Any ideas with that?

Comment: ok, nevermind, it is reading the css, but the values are not defaulting to ''. They are defaulting background-color to 'transparent' and background-image to 'none'. So I just adjusted the function above accordingly.

Thanks for your help!